# How to remove sources in maven

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm using https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/ to generate sources from wsdl files. I'm doing multiple executions(for different wsdls) with different sourceDestDir. This is working as expected and it is generating sources in different directories.

But the plugin is also adding all of these sourceDestDir's to build sources and the maven-compiler-plugin tries to compile them automatically.

I want to prevent this from happening. i.e I want to remove the source directories added by jaxws-maven-plugin so that I can define what should be compiled and what shouldn't be. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide the `jaxws-maven-plugin` configuration? To which pahse are you binding it?

Comment: the jaxws-mabven-plugin adds the directories as compile source root - https://svn.java.net/svn/jax-ws-commons~svn/tags/jaxws-maven-plugin-2.3/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jax_ws_commons/jaxws/AbstractJaxwsMojo.java and I ended up writing a custom plugin to get rid of this(and some others